# not able to ouptut mac address when provisioning multiple vm's

Tags: terraform

so i am trying to deploy multiple vm's but when i try to output the mac adrress it is failing with

output.mac: Resource 'vsphere_virtual_machine.vm' not found for variable 'vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.network_interface.0.mac_address'

can someone tell me why it is failing or what is wrong in my code

```
   resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
      count="2"
      name             = "name-${count.index+1}"
      resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
      datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
      num_cpus = 2
      memory   = 1024
      guest_id = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id}"
      scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type}"

      network_interface {
        network_id   = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
        adapter_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]}"
      }

      disk {
        label            = "disk0"
        size             = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size}"
        eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
        thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
      }

      clone {
        template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"

        customize {
          linux_options {
            host_name = "terraform-test1"
            domain    = "test.internal"
          }

          network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "10.0.0.${count.index+2}"
        ipv4_netmask = 24
      }

      ipv4_gateway = "10.0.0.1"
    }
  }
}

output "mac"{
value ="${vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.network_interface.0.mac_address}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute reference "network_interface" for resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" So you cannot output network interface details. Please check resource document link https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html.

```
Following attributes are exported on the base level of this resource:

id - The UUID of the virtual machine.
reboot_required - Value internal to Terraform used to determine if a configuration set change requires a reboot. This value is only useful during an update process and gets reset on refresh.
vmware_tools_status - The state of VMware tools in the guest. This will determine the proper course of action for some device operations.
vmx_path - The path of the virtual machine's configuration file in the VM's datastore.
imported - This is flagged if the virtual machine has been imported, or the state has been migrated from a previous version of the resource. It influences the behavior of the first post-import apply operation. See the section on importing below.
change_version - A unique identifier for a given version of the last configuration applied, such the timestamp of the last update to the configuration.
uuid - The UUID of the virtual machine. Also exposed as the id of the resource.
default_ip_address - The IP address selected by Terraform to be used with any provisioners configured on this resource. Whenever possible, this is the first IPv4 address that is reachable through the default gateway configured on the machine, then the first reachable IPv6 address, and then the first general discovered address if neither exist. If VMware tools is not running on the virtual machine, or if the VM is powered off, this value will be blank.
guest_ip_addresses - The current list of IP addresses on this machine, including the value of default_ip_address. If VMware tools is not running on the virtual machine, or if the VM is powered off, this list will be empty.
moid: The managed object reference ID of the created virtual machine.
vapp_transport - Computed value which is only valid for cloned virtual machines. A list of vApp transport methods supported by the source virtual machine or template.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just if anyone interested, this works for me  :)

```
output "mac"{
value ="${vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.network_interface[0].mac_address}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on an older Terraform (0.11.8)  I had to use:

```
output "mac"{
value ="${vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.network_interface.0.mac_address}"
}
```